# Perl SOAP timeout does not work

Tags: perl, soap, timeout

I am calling a webservice which is returning 80.000 records. Because record count is too big, call ends with timeout. But the issue I culd not understand is that call ends earlier or later than the time I defined. My code is below, I defined timeout as 10 minutes (600 sec.)

```
my $soap = SOAP::Lite    
    -> on_action( sub { join '/', @_ } )
     -> uri($uri)
     -> proxy($proxy, timeout => 600)    
     -> ns($ns1,"soapenv")
     -> ns($ns2,"ns2");
```

But call sometimes ends with timeout in 5 minutes , sometimes ends in 18 minutes. What is the reason of this? Why it does not end in 10 minutes?

And what can I do more to prevent timeout? It is sure that reason of timeout is record cout because when record count is decreased it works.

Comment: You're sure the timeout is not from the server side? Do you control the server? This is far-fetched, but I had a db-admin colleague kill long queries manually on a db server he was monitoring once in a while because he thought they slow down production. We used to go talk to him so he is distracted while we ran those queries...

Comment: I am calling customer's web service and don't know if they have a timeout limit. But when I set timeout to 10 minutes, sometimes it ends with timeout in 30 minutes. Even if server has a timeout, my timeout duration should not pass

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well, the proxy timeout wasnt working for me. This code worked however:

$soap->transport->timeout(600);
or 
$self->{soap}->transport->timeout(600);